# Google cloud storage access token for speech-to-text

Tags: speech-to-text

I can’t figure out how to use longer files than one minute in the speech-to-text api, I have google cloud storage, but I can’t get the access code to that.

Comment: Access code should be the same as for speech recognition, you just need to create the bucket in your console project

Comment: Thanks, then there is something else that is wrong...